# LaTeX complicated headers and footers

Tags: header-footer, article

I recently came across this document which I am trying to recreate, and this is what I'm dealing with:

---

[image: first page]

---

[image: second page and so on]

---

I have no clue where to start in trying to replicate a header and footer like that, I new to LaTeX classes so I'm not really sure where to start.

Youtube is pretty plain on this topic and Overleaf learn section doesn't help me much either.

I really want to create a .cls file in order to adapt it to other related documentation...

If anyone could point me in any direction it would be great, or if you already have some experience and easily recreate it yourself, that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to define two `pagestyle`s, for example with `fancyhdr` package (depend on which document class you intend to use): One for the first page and one for the other pages. Content of headers and footers you can recreate by use of a tables. On this site you can find plenty of examples how to do this.

Comment: As @Zarko told: There are lots of questions about page header and footer. So the direction should be clear and you should show, what you've already tried, and explain, where you failed.

Comment: The [Overleaf page on headers and footers](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers) is quite extensive.  I'd be surprised if it doesn't cover what you want.  And I wouldn't worry about a cls file for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lastpage,geometry,array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
  margin = 1.5in,
  headheight = 45pt % Adjust this with a change in your image size
}

\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{% Center footer
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
      \rule[0.5em]{0.35\textwidth}{.4pt}
      \includegraphics[height=1em]{example-image}
      \rule[0.5em]{0.35\textwidth}{.4pt} \\
      \bfseries Page \thepage~of \pageref{LastPage} \\
      Some address in Randomville \\
      who.cares.com $|$ 123-456-7890 $|$ who@cares.com
    \end{tabular}
  }
}

\fancypagestyle{defaultpagestyle}{%
  \pagestyle{firstpagestyle}% Duplicate firstpagestyle, but update the header
  \fancyhead[C]{% Center header
    \rule[2em]{0.3\textwidth}{.4pt}
    \includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image}
    \rule[2em]{0.3\textwidth}{.4pt}
  }
}

% Set page style to defaultpagestyle
\pagestyle{defaultpagestyle}

\begin{document}

% Change this page to have a different page style
\thispagestyle{firstpagestyle}

\vspace*{-5\baselineskip}% Move up on the page

% Set first page "header"/title
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} w{c}{\textwidth} @{}}
  \includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image} \\
  \scshape Some Foreign Place \\
  \scshape With Interesting Stuff That Is Useful \\
  \scshape And Has Knowledge To Share \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries\large 
  An interesting article title that is bold and impressive \\
  maybe with reference to funding partners and colleagues \\
  and other valuable contributors
\end{center}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```